# How to remove white space using powershell in multiple text file in the same folder?

Tags: powershell

folder name is: `c:\home\alltext\`

inside has: 2 text files with different names(each text contents extra whitespace that I want to trim)

```
   text1.txt
   text2.txt
```

I don't want to use notepad++ and do one by one text.txt if I have more than 2 command.

I tried PowerShell it returns both text1 and text2 together in same one text.txt.

How can I trim them in one command and return individual txt?
This is my command:

```
(get-content c:\home\alltext\*.txt).trim() -ne '' | Set-content c:\home\alltext\*.txt
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to process the input files *one by one*:

```bash
Get-ChildItem c:\home\alltext*.txt | ForEach-Object {
  Set-Content -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Value (($_ | Get-Content).Trim() -ne '')
}
```

Note that PowerShell never preserves the original character encoding when reading text files, so you may have to use the `-Encoding` parameter with [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content).

---

As for **what you tried**:

`(get-content c:\home\alltext*.txt).trim() -ne ''` streams the non-blank lines of *all* files matching wildcard expression `c:\home\alltext*.txt`, across file boundaries.

Perhaps surprisingly, not only does `Set-Content`'s (positionally implied) `-Path` parameter *accept* wildcard expressions too, it writes the *same* content (the stringified versions of whatever input it receives) to *whatever files happen to match that wildcard expression*.

This problematic behavior is discussed in [GitHub issue #6729](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6729); unfortunately, it was decided to retain the current behavior.